# .NET Type of return value

Tags: .net, vb.net, system.reflection

Seems an ambiguous question but the matter is that I have something like:

```
Dim a As MyObject
a = GetData(a.GetType) 

Function GetData(tp as Type)
     DotheWork(tp)
End Function
```

So, what I want to know if there's any way to omit that Type parameter in GetData() and obtain it from the variable that I have on the left side of the assignment. (Basically cause I'm usinge Reflection in GetData() so I need an instance from parameter's type)

Could it be possible??? Many thanks!

Comment: I've removed the C# tag since this seems to be more about vb.net syntax than .net

Comment: You should start by turning on `Option Strict`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible because `GetData()` is evaluated prior to the assignement. What you can do is an generic approach:

```
dim a as MyObject = GetData(of MyObject)()

Function GetData(Of T)()
    Dim _t As Type = GetType(T)
    DotheWork(_t)
End Function
```

That's how I would do this.

And please note that `a.GetType` in your initial code will fail because a is Nothing and your  function does not return anything so `a` will be assigned nothing after `GetData()`, too.

Maybe you wanted to achive something like this:

```
Function GetData(Of T As { IMyType, New })()

    Dim instance As T = Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)()
    DotheWork(instance)
    Return instance

End Function

Function DotheWork(instance As IMyType)
    instance.Init()
End Function

Interface IMyType
    Sub Init()
End Interface
```